# How to deal with ajax errors in production?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vuejs2, vue.js

In development I usually do something like this:

```
fetchFaqData() {
  this.$http.get('/services/getfaq').then((response) => {
    this.faqs = response.data;
}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

This is fine when you are working in development to view if something goes wrong with your ajax request. What do you do with this bit of code in production though?

I assume it might not be wise or preferable to show this in production through a console.log. What do people do in this case?

Write it to a log file or something? I usually use quite a lot of these ajax blocks in my code where I console.log out the error response. I see examples like these a lot too. Do people just go over their code when they are done and log this to a log or something? Or preferably do that from the start?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried out error reporting services like sentry?

Comment: If you're using jQuery then you can use `$.ajaxSetup()` to define a generic error handler which applies to all AJAX requests

Comment: first of all - replace Vue Resource with Axios as VueResource is not longer supported.

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy I have not tried sentry yet. It says it is free up to 10k events. One event simply being something like a console.log? This seems pretty nice and I doubt we would hit 10k events in that case.

Comment: @MU What is wrong with Vue-resource?

Comment: I don't see why I should switch to axios since their last commit was the 11th of january. Even vue-resource gets updated more often. Just because it is not 'officially' being supported anymore does that mean that there is anything wrong with it. It is easier to setup with Vue imo and it is what I am used to using.

Comment: Do you want to display that error on your App interface so everyone could see that error message if it's happen - or make it available only for you ?

Comment: @BelminBedak Our visitors have nothing to do with these error messages so they shouldn't see these messages. I would love a solution where messages are being logged to the console for developers in development and sent to a local log file or server in production though. This would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Well since Vue 2 supports SSR maybe something could be done with NodeJS.but what about bugsnag https://www.bugsnag.com/pricing/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same situation, luckily I was fetching a JSON content, so I had to intercept and validate the reponse as:

```
   this.$http.get('/api/json').then((response) => {
    var json = JSON.parse(response.body); 

    if(!json){
        // alert error or do something
    }

   }, (response) => {
    // console.log(response);
  });
```

Hopefully, someone will provide a better answer for both of us

Comment: I see that something like sentry.io pick up things like console.log messages for you when you have it installed. I am not sure about sending these kind of error message to a third party though. Besides that, you have to pay for more than 10k events. Even though that might not happen soon I think I would rather have a local solution. I'm going to research some more while people hopefully provide some more answers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, normally you will process your errors in 2 ways:

1. If the error does not affect the workflow of your system and user experience, you can probably ignore it. If it is something important, you will be able to analyze logs from the server and see why it does response with an error. Otherwise if it is a client-side problem - well, write tests mate or ask your users to report bugs :)
2. If the error does affect the workflow of the system or user experience you might want to handle the error and try to make sure your user experience is not hurt.

**Examples:**

If you are requesting the a profile picture from the server that does not exist, try to use some fallback user icon.

If your server crashed and the response was timed out, you can show some notification/dialog/message saying "Ooups, something's going wrong".

**To summarize:**

Show users human-readable errors if it is important for THEIR experience.

Client-side-ajax-errors are not very important until they go in pair with some server fails because, for example, one can have bad connection and his calls can be failing.

Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Even if the user workflow is not affected because I handle the error properly and display an alternative, friendly error message or prevent something nasty from showing up I still can not see if something went wrong personally. To analyze logs from something that went wrong in the javascript(like a bad ajax requests). I first need a system to log to, which this entire question is about. So I get what you are saying and this is always of concern but I need a solution for when something actually went wrong even if the users does not see it.

Comment: @Stephan-v you dont need to analyze logs from ajax because ajax calls can fail even if there is no error, for example because of bad internet connection. What Im trying to say is that you need to analyze logs from your backend, not frontend.

Comment: And in your backend you of course have to store all the request logs, system logs, everything. You can use various tools to analyze those. Otherwise is just a timewaster.